# Spring batch aggregate result from multiple itemwriter

Tags: spring-batch

I am using the partitioner to split the data to multiple steps. Each step will do the same work parallel. My problem is after each step completed, I want to aggregate the result from different itemwriter. Like the total successful and failed cnt in the all writer.

Is there some way I can do that in the spring batch ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably coming too late, but I stumbled upon this so will give answer.

Partitioned step has [aggregator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/StepExecutionAggregator.html) and you can add it to partitioned step. You get collection of all step executions and you can collect sums from all steps. From documentation:

> Strategy for a aggregating step executions, usually when they are the
>   result of partitioned or remote execution.